# Euler Angles on $\mathbb{R}P^3$?

Tags: general-topology, coordinate-systems, rotations

I am curious if anyone can point me to a reference where the Euler angle coordinates are visualized as a parametrization of $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Bonus points if there are visualization aids for the quaternion and axis-angle parametrization as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you're asking about projective space because you're aware that $\mathbf{RP}^{3}$ is diffeomorphic to the rotation group $SO(3)$...?

Comment: Yes, I am speaking of Real Projective 3-Space. As I understand it, unit quaternions provide a Cartesian parametrization of $S^3$, which we chop in half and identify antipodal points at the equator to get $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "at the equator." We regard a vector $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ as a "pure" quaternion, zero real part, $ v =xi + yj + zk.$ Given a unit quaternion $q,$ with conjugate $\bar{q},$ our rotated vector is $q v \bar{q}.$ Short proof that this is also a pure quaternion. Meanwhile, $q$ and $-q$ give precisely the same rotation.

Comment: I'm talking about the equator of $S^3$, which is a 2-sphere, $S^2$. Unit quaternions (with non zero real part) provide a Cartesian cover of $S^3$.

Comment: My earlier comment was unclear. The questions were: 1. Are you happy with Euler angles and axis-angle descriptions of $SO(3)$? 2. Are you happy with the axis-angle description of the diffeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $\mathbf{RP}^{3}$? and 3. Are you (therefore) looking for a description in the language of projective space rather than in terms of rotation matrices/unit quaternions?

Comment: From a slightly different angle: what would 'visualized' mean here? Are you looking for a volumetric visualization, are you looking for slices on which the Euler angles can be seen, or what?

Comment: Hi all. Thank you for your replies. Mostly what I am looking for is a way to visualize Euler angles on $\mathbb{R}P^3$ as coordinate curves and coordinate surfaces, i.e. from a differential geometry perspective.

Maybe it would be better to visualize quaternion coordinate curves and coordinate surfaces first. First, an analogy to $x,y,z$ on $S^2$. Let $x$ and $y$ be the coordinates. An $x$ coordinate surface is a $y-z$ plane which intersects $S^2$ to give a circle, $S^1$, a $y$-coordinate curve.

Spherical polar coordinates on $S^2$ have coordinate curves which foliate the surface in

Comment: latitudes and longitudes.

I suspect Euler angles on $\mathbb{R}P^3$ make the volume into a lattice of something like parallels, meridians, and hypermeridians. But then I am pretty sure I read somewhere that it is the hyperspherical coordinates that are responsible for doing this, and Euler angles (I don't think) are hyperspherical coordinates on $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: Axis-angle on $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is easy to visualize if we consider $\mathbb{R}P^3$ to be a 3D disk of radius $\pi$ with its antipodal points on the boundary identified. If we take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be coordinates for ${\bf n}$, and $\theta$ to be the rotation angle, then a constant ${\bf n}$ defines a $\theta$ coordinate curve which is a diameter of the disk. A $\theta$ coordinate surface is a 2-sphere of radius $\theta$. This surface would be foliated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coordinate curves: latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: You might find valuable material in the doctoral thesis by J.E. Mebius : 
[Applications of Quaternions to Dynamical Simulation, Computer Graphics and Biomechanics](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A5e7abfd6-3780-474d-bbff-eea495fd4bf4) . The PDF is a free download.

Comment: Great reference to this author, thank you! The TU Delft site seems to be down right now but I found another work of his: A topological representation of the system of extended Euler angles. This is very close to what I'm looking for!